# How to remove react-native-splash-screen dependency of android

Tags: android, react-native

When I `yarn remove react-native-splash-screen` for my react native project.

The android compiler report a error message:

```
Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-splash-screen:
  - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

How to check this error out and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run 
`react-native unlink react-native-splash-screen`

and `npm uninstall react-native-splash-screen`

Comment: @yuanlai You can find the path and remove it manually, but manual removal is not recommended because there may be missing parts.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. Go on the terminal and write :

Step - 1 :

```bash
react-native unlink react-native-splash-screen
```

Step - 2 : Go to package.json and remove the line of `react-native-splash-screen`

Step -3 :

```bash
# npm
npm i
# or if you use yarn
yarn
```

And its unlinked and uninstalled and removed